# Change date-format in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Rails and trying to import a logfile. The date-format that the log has is `yyyymmdd;hhmmss`:

```
20121216;233550
```

My MySQL server uses this to for its insert statements:

```
 MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS
```

How can I convert this string-format to the date-format?

Comment: You'll have to write some code; that's a non-standard date format.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, it is expected that you will attempt to solve the problem first, and show a sample of the code you used, along with any error messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
require 'date'
DateTime.strptime('20121216;233550', '%Y%m%d;%H%M%S').strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

No magic, really.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that format remains fixed and contains no errors, you can create a Time object with:

```
d="20121216;233550"
Time.mktime(d[0..3], d[4..5],d[6..7],d[9..10],d[11.12],d[13..14])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Rails (which loads ActiveSupport), that format appears parseable using [Time#parse](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html#method-i-parse):

`Time.parse(source_dt).strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')`